# Why won't simpleXML_load_file() open this file?

Tags: php

```
$feed_url ="http://www.example.com/examplestring?format=RSS";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$RSS_DOC = simpleXML_load_file($feed_url);
if (!$RSS_DOC) {
   echo "Failed loading XML\n";
  foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {

      echo "\t", $error->message;
  }   
}
```

I've the code above to load other rss feeds such as:

```
http://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
```

and

```
$feed_url ="http://www.quiltexamples.com/rss.xml";
```

However with the URL that I'm currently trying to load, I get:

```
PHP Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://www.example.com/examplestring?format=RSS): 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
in ExamplelogParser.php on line 7
Failed loading XML

failed to load external entity "http://www.example.com/examplestring?format=RSS"
```

Comment: _HTTP request failed!_ So it's a bad URL or the server is configured to not give it to you based on some criteria (user agent, etc...)

Comment: php curl is your friend :) in this case check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553678/read-xml-data-from-url-using-curl-and-php

Comment: @Arsh: no. That won't help here.

Comment: The server you are talking to doesn't like your http request. Most likely because you haven't supplied an accept header saying you will accept xml. See http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver - thanks, I ended up adding the user agent string as per some other stack exchange thread. The user agent wasn't set in my php.ini. I set it to 'php' and it worked. `libxml_set_streams_context(
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'php'            
            )
        )
    )
);`